# WiFi stuck on "Turning on..." after rooting Samsung Galaxy NotePro P900

Tags: wi-fi, root-access

After rooting my tablet the WiFi stopped working, it activating it just makes it go "turning on..." for a while and then shut down. Tried reflashing stock rom, tried doing a factory reset - Nothing worked.

WiFi worked fine before root so its probably not a hardware issue, unless the root process can physically break the WiFi?

I am certain I used the correct model to flash the root (Using P900 WiFi only)